# Nim counting over multiple threads

Tags: nim-lang

I'm currently trying to count how many times I requested a website. In python I would just use a global variable but I have no idea how I would write this in nim.

```
import httpclient

proc threadMain(a: int) {.thread.} =

    var client = newHttpClient()
    while true:
      try:
        var r = client.getContent("URL")
        echo "sent"
        #Count here
      except:
        echo "error"

var thread: array[0..10, Thread[int]]

for i in 0..10:
  thread[i].createThread(threadMain, i)

thread.joinThreads()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is explained almost as a copy in the "[Nim in Action](https://www.manning.com/books/nim-in-action)" book, page 174.

First of all, if you used a global in Python, you had to use a lock or risk a race condition. The thing is not different in Nim: first create a global, and guard it using a [lock](https://nim-lang.org/docs/locks.html).

```
import locks

var counterLock: Lock
initLock(counterLock)
var counter {.guard: counterLock.} = 0
```

Now use a `withLock` where you need to update the counter:

```
withLock counterLock:
  counter.inc
```

The chapter of the book related to paralellism/concurrency is very good. You should check it, as it also explains concurrency (your code is an example of concurrency being better than threading) or how to use [Channels](https://nim-lang.org/docs/channels.html) to pass data between threads, for example.

Comment: Thanks, worked just fine. Btw. I think you have a typo its "import locks" not "import locks"